# Jquery animate next div over set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have asked a similar question which got me this answer, however when trying to move it over to usable markup I am hot having any luck.

Essentially I have rows of 4 divs by 3 divs, when they are clicked I need the following div to expand over all of the other divs in the grid and toggle when needed. I have tried using animate and toggle to no avail. One example using tables here http://jsfiddle.net/gGc5K/.

I need the following markup to work in the same way (with a toggle to close) using the nexr method if possible.

Thanks

```
  <!--div in the grid--><div class="gridBox" id="one"></div>
    <div class="pop" id="bigOne">Content here and a toggle link</div><!--This div needs to expand over the full grid-->

 <!--div in the grid--><div class="gridBox" id="two"></div>
    <div class="pop" id="bigTwo">Content here and a toggle link</div><!--This div needs to expand over the full grid-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var top = 0,
    left = 0;

$("td").click(function() {
    var ref = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('currentAnimated')) {
        $(this).css({
            "z-index": 1
        }).animate({
            top: top,
            left: left,
            width: "40px",
            height: "39px"
        }, "4s", function() {
            ref.removeClass('currentAnimated');
        })
    } else {
        top = $(this).position().top;
        left = $(this).position().left;
        $(this).css({
            "z-index": 1
        }).animate({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "120px",
            height: "120px"
        }, "4s", function() {
            ref.addClass('currentAnimated')
        });
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gGc5K/4/)**

Comment: Cheersm I don't think i made myself clear enough, what i want it to do is in the code sample above, there is a grid layout with each cell being a div, when you click on the div it will animate and show the next dive under which is hidden until that point